# Why is solution to a linear equation a vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

I am new in Linear Algebra and I have encountered the concept of Solutions of linear equations. According to the textbook I use, a solution of a linear equation is a vector whose components satisfy the equation. However, I am puzzled by the choice of "vectors" specifically. Why is it not defined as a point whose coordinates are the same as the values that satisfy the linear equation? After all, a vector is more than just its components; it is also a set of points and its "components" define its magnitude and direction. A point, on the other hand, is a single entity with no additional properties. No magic. I think It's just a bit more intuitive to think of it this way instead. I can also anticipate that Vectors have a deeper meaning that relates them to linear equation systems but I can't tell what exactly. I'm going through the chapters and I'm still waiting for the "Bingo! I figured it out."

Comment: Points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are the same thing as vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Viewing it as a vector (rather than a list of values that you "substitute into" the equations) allows you to bring the tools of linear algebra to bear.

Comment: Perhaps you are limited to thinking of vectors as arrows. Linear algebra is the study of vector spaces and vectors in these spaces are generalizations of those arrows that are less intuitive than points. The vectors in $\mathbb R^n$ are points so when you say it is more intuitive to think of the solutions as points you are saying that it is intuitive to think of them as vectors.

Comment: Understanding the distinction between "a vector is an arrow" and "a vector is an element in a set that obeys the vector space axioms" is very important in linear algebra, especially when you want to look at vector spaces that aren't just $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

If $(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ is a solution to a set of homogeneous linear equations, then so are $(2x_1, 2x_2, ..., 2x_n)$ and $(-\frac{3}{5}x_1, -\frac{3}{5}x_2, ..., -\frac{3}{5}x_n)$

Also, if $(y_1, y_2, ... y_n)$ is also an solution, then so is $(x_1+y_1, x_2+ y_2, .... x_n+y_n)$.

This ability to multiply a solution set (by the same number), and to add together two solutions, and still have a solution, is **exactly** the "magic" that linear algebra formalizes - and "vector" is the name that we have adopted to call mathematical things that can be multiplied and added in just the ways mentioned above.

You can take a list of values and think of them as either a point or a vector, but once you start adding them and scaling them? Those are what one does with vectors.